# RSA algorithm query on size of the message

Tags: algorithm, rsa

In RSA algorithm, it is given that plain text size must be less than or equal to ( key size - 11 ).

why it is like that. what is that 11 actually...?

Comment: Can you provide a source on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a requirement when PKCS1 padding is used. "Naked" RSA, insecure though it is, can do stuff up to the key size in length, and OAEP padding depends on the hash algorithm you're using.

From [the PKCS1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2.1):

```
   Steps:

   1. Length checking: If mLen > k - 11, output "message too long" and
      stop.

   2. EME-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding:

      a. Generate an octet string PS of length k - mLen - 3 consisting
         of pseudo-randomly generated nonzero octets.  The length of PS
         will be at least eight octets.

      b. Concatenate PS, the message M, and other padding to form an
         encoded message EM of length k octets as

            EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M.
```

As per that at least 11 bytes are prepended to the plaintext. 0x00 and 0x02 and then PS, which has a length of "at least eight octets" and then 0x00. So 3 + 8 = 11.